# Run an Access 2003 Application in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

What is the effort to migrate an Access 2003 Application to Access 2007? Are there any problems converting mdb to accdb? Which modifications must be done?

Comment: This would be entirely based on the application being migrated, and is impossible for anyone to answer. Just migrate it, and deal with issues that come up. Make sure to back up the original application completely; if everything gets ruined, just restore from the backup and start over (or leave it as an Access 2003 app).

Comment: @KenWhite that makes a good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This would be entirely based on the application being migrated, and is impossible for anyone to answer. It's like asking "How much will it cost to modernize the kitchen in my house?". Without knowing a lot more (what needs to be done, what kind of new appliances you want, the selection of cabinets, countertops and flooring you'd like, the labor and material costs in your area, the condition of the existing structure), it's impossible to predict.

Just migrate it, and deal with issues that come up. Make sure to back up the original application completely; if everything gets ruined, just restore from the backup and start over (or leave it as an Access 2003 app).

Comment: This can be a doozy but nothing that you can't get through

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that it's a bit of an open question, there are some guidelines that will help you decide on how difficult it will be. Take a look at this:
http://www.sagekey.com/support_forum.aspx?g=posts&t=393

Since none of my DB's that I have upgraded involve the major pitfalls described in that article, I have had very little issues. One I did just last night took me about 30 minutes.